# return callback() and callback() inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

See below code, if I were to remove all the return keywords, the function still work as expected, which causes me to get really confused with callback() and return callback() when mixing with promise

Can someone explain to me, which of the following `return` can be removed?

is the `done()` function ever executed?

```
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, (email, password, done) => {
  User.find({ where: { email } }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false);
    }
    return user.validPassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
      if (!isMatch) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    return done(err, false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does `done()` return a Promise?

Comment: You really ought to promisify that `user.validPassword` method.

Comment: No, the function does no more work the same if you remove all `return` keywords.

Comment: What promise libary are you using?

Comment: this may has nothing to do with whether if it is inside a promise. I dont even know how to ask the questions. I am especially confused by the ```return``` before ```user.validPassword```

Comment: @Bergi I understand it works without all the ```return```, but i dont understand how and why it works. I dont think ```done()``` return promise. not using any promise libary.

Comment: @Alex: "*it works without all the `return`*" - **no** it does not. You would at least have to introduce a lot of `else` blocks if you omit the `return`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `return` just break user.Find and user.validPassword callbacks execution. As an example, it can be replace by else conditions as follow:

```
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, (email, password, done) => {
    User.find({ where: { email } }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            done(null, false);
        }
        else {
            user.validPassword(password, (err, isMatch) => { // return at this point is not needed, because there is nothing to break after this function
                if (err) {
                    done(err, false);
                }
                else{
                    if (!isMatch) {
                        done(null, false);
                    }
                    else {
                        done(null, user);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        done(err, false);
    });
});
```

As you can see, `return` allows get rid of numerous else conditions.

[`return callback()`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/callback-return) is a good practice:

Comment: Thanks for clarify this. Now I feel this is a bad question. I guess I got really confused with all the callbacks returning callbacks mixing with Promise.